# Get Key Value From Firebase To Google Sheets

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database, google-sheets

This is my script:

```
function getFacturasClientesExistentes() {
var firebaseUrl = "*****/userselectedsquads/za1/contest1";
var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
var data = base.getData();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Items");

var num = 2;
range = sheet.getRange("A"+num+":G"+num+"");
for(var i in data) {
var values = [
[ data[i].dreamteam, data[i].starteam, data[i].p1, data[i].p2, data[i].p3, data[i].p4, ]
];
range.setValues(values);
num += 1;
range = sheet.getRange("A"+num+":G"+num+"");
} 
}
```

Currently I am retrieving value of each child.

But now I also want to retrieve child value.

How can I retrieve that?

My database structure I want to retrieve those children from:

[image: database structure]

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

If I understood your question correctly, you want to retrieve documents listed under `constest1` collection instead of a list of top-level collections.

**Solution**

If the abovementioned is true, you can provide `path` parameter to `getData()` to drill into the collections at the specified level (see note 4 for reference to the library you likely use since there is no "native" `FirebaseApp` service in GAS).

**Optimizations**

Regardless of the issue, you should optimize your code for it to be more efficient and readable (see notes below for details). Here is the updated code:

```
function getFacturasClientesExistentes() {
  var firebaseUrl = "*****/userselectedsquads/za1/contest1";

  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  var data = base.getData("za1/contest1");

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Items");

  var numRows = data.length;

  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows, 7);

  var newValues = data.map(function (item) {
    return [
      item.dreamteam, 
      item.starteam, 
      item.p1, 
      item.p2, 
      item.p3, 
      item.p4
    ];
  });

  range.setValues(newValues);
}
```

**Notes**

1. `Range` represents a "live" collection (in a sense that that `getValue()`, `getValues()` methods will return currently set values), you don't need to reassign it (and certainly not in a loop - see note 2).
2. `getRange()`, `getValue()`, `setValue()` etc are I/O operations and thus are slower (much slower on large collections) than in-memory manipulation. Thus, try to reduce them as much as possible - never do them in a loop, for example (unless no other choice).
3. Always declare your variables (note to `range` var in your code) with `var` (for `const` & `let` it goes without saying). Although there will be no error in non-strict mode (one of the quarks of JavaScript), the variable without the keyword will be treated as *global* due to [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).
4. If `getData()` of the `FirebaseApp` (You use [this](https://github.com/RomainVialard/FirebaseApp/blob/master/src/Code.gs) third-party lib, right?) returns an `object[]`, so you could map over the values directly.

Comment: I want to retrive zaid(T1)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Just to make sure - you want to limit the query to just the `zaid(T1)` document? Btw, am I correct that you use the abovementioned library? If so, have you tried specifying the path as described (Apologies if I got it wrong - I don't use one myself, but the docs suggest doing just that)

Comment: Currently i am retriving the documents in zaid(T1)etc now i want to retrive documents with the child in witch the document exists.

Comment: Currently Retriving documents from all child in contests1 but now i also want to retrive that child value.

Comment: Ok, if I got what you mean, how about going a step up in the `path` param and retrieving everything under `za1`? You should receive a collection of contests which have (teams?) your desired items as nested objects

Comment: I am confused what u r telling.

Comment: Well, I am a bit too :) You mentioned in the first comment that you query records of `zaid(T1...Tn)`, then in the second - the records of `contest1`... Could you update the question with the structure of the response you currently get in `data`?